# How to set attributes for stdClass object at the time object creation

Tags: php, stdclass

I want to set attribute for a *stdClass* object in a single statement.
I don't have any idea about it. I know the following things

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->attr = 'loremipsum';
```

It takes two statements.

```
$obj = (object) array('attr'=>'loremipsum');
```

It takes single statement but it is not direct method.

```
$obj = new stdClass(array('attr'=>'loremipsum'));
```

It is not working.

Comment: You cannot do this using `stdClass`. You will need to create your own custom class which has a constructor.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
$obj = (object) array(
    'attr'=>'loremipsum'
);
```

Actually, that's as direct as it's going to get. Even a custom constructor won't be able to do this in a single expression.

The `(object)` cast *might* actually be a simple translation from an array, because internally the properties are stored in a hash as well.

You could create a base class like this:

```
abstract class MyObject
{
    public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
    {
        foreach ($attributes as $name => $value) {
            $this->{$name} = $value;
        }
    }
}

class MyWhatever extends MyObject
{
}

$x = new MyWhatever(array(
    'attr' => 'loremipsum',
));
```

Doing so will lock up your constructor though, requiring each class to call its parent constructor when overridden.

Comment: Why you are creating "MyWhatever"? you can directly use the "MyObject" by removing the abstract keyword, right?

Comment: Sure, if you're okay with having instances of the base class you can remove the abstract keyword :)

Answer (score 7):

Though Ja͢ck gives a good answer, it is important to stress that the PHP interpreter itself has a method for describing [how to properly represent an object or variable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php):

```
php > $someObject = new stdClass();
php > $someObject->name = 'Ethan';
php > var_export($someObject);
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'name' => 'Ethan',
))
```

Interestingly, using `stdClass::__set_state` fails to create a stdClass object, thus displaying it as such is likely [a bug in `var_export()`](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67918). **However, it does illustrate that there is no straightforward method to create the stdClass object with attributes set at the time of object creation.**

Comment: Good to know. By the by, What command you used to get php command line interpreter like python interpretor (type, enter, see output)?

Comment: From the Bash CLI: `php -a`

Comment: :) Thanks (5 more to go...)

Answer (score 4):

```
        foreach ($attributes as $name => $value) {
            if (property_exists(self::class, $name)) {
                $this->{$name} = $value;
            }
        }
```

is cleanest because it will set an arbitrary attribute if you print_r(get_object_vars($obj)) of returned object if attribute does not exist.