# Assign Value to STD class object array

Tags: php, object, std

I need a little assistance with the STD class objects.

```
        $checking_w_products = explode("-",$orderline_val->products[$x]->sku);
        if(count($checking_w_products)>1)
        {
            if($checking_w_products[0]=="W")
            {

                $orderline_val->products[$x] = (object) array(
                    'sku '=>$checking_w_products[1]
                );

            }
            else
            {
                $orderline_val->products[$x] = (object) array(
                    'sku '=>'ahmad'
                );
            }
        }

        echo $orderline_val->products[$x]->sku;
        die;
```

I am trying to update the product sku but somehow it is not doing so..It just keeps the value of

```
 $orderline_val->products[$x]->sku
```

as it is without updating it. I used [this]:[How to set attributes for stdClass object at the time object creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761335/how-to-set-attributes-for-stdclass-object-at-the-time-object-creation) example too but no effect...

If you can then please guide me how can I update the value of

```
$orderline_val->products[$x]->sku;
```

Thanks

Comment: what's wrong with $orderline_val->products[$x]->sku = 'something'

Comment: i tried it myself but it doesnt work either...

Comment: see if changing 'sku ' to 'sku' (trim the space) would make a difference

Comment: no that didnt work either :( :(